# Sending data in a call from flex to javascript

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3, flex4.5

I have implemented a export to excel feature for my flex datagrid. The export functionality is done from backend, so I send a `urlRequest` using `ExternalInterface`.call like 
`ExternalInterface.call("window.open", urlRequest.url ....)`. I understand its a GET call right now.

Now I need to POST some data as a part of this urlRequest. How can I achieve that (may be using urlVariable). Please remember I need to open that "Open/Save" dialog window as per current implementation only.

Answer (score 0):

Call a function in javascript which will make a POST request. Use ExternalInterface.call to send parameters to that javascript function.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
ExternalInterface.call("javascriptMethodname", your data);
```

put the same method name in your html file

```
function javascriptMethodname(mydata){....... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the sample utility here: [log debug messages via browser console](http://marumushi.com/news/debugging-as3-with-firebugs-console)